# What jobs will people have on a frontier world? Who do we select for a ship of settlers?

Tags: space-colonization

When a world is settled, certain kinds of expertise will probably be needed first.

Growing food, building housing and infrastructure, medical care, and education for the children of everyone may be more essential than banking or an entertaiment industry.

There will be some kind of administration to organize everything and represent the interests of the origin world. And there will be scientists relevant to the world (geologists, biologists, maybe archeologists or linguists), but no academia with theoretical physicists, philosophers, or political science.

There have been many frontier situations on our planet, most notable the American Frontier, but also the settlement of Australia by Europeans. We can certainly look there to get some idea of what jobs where most needed in those situations, but the American West was a "free for all" and drew many who were unqualified but wanted to find a better life, while space settlement might be a more organized affair, with a preselection of who can go, so there may be some notable differences also.

You can either answer what kind of jobs or expertise *will* be needed on a frontier world, or what will *not* be needed, depending on what you think will make your answer more concise. I'm not looking for an exaustive list of jobs, but more for a list of essential (or non-essential) fields of expertise, but you might want to give some examples to explain certain choices.

To answer the question, you can think of staffing a ship with settlers. Who would you send? Who not?

---

Frame:

- the planet is inabitable: we are settling, not terraforming; so it has a breathable atmosphere, water, soil (which means, plant and animal life)
- the purpose is settling, not exploration or exploitation
- this is the first wave (there might be a second wave, or the children of the settlers can grow up to be whatever they need after the pioneer phase from the knowledge they brought)
- if these people can fly to a different solar system to colonize it, they don't need miners and road workers; machines will do the hard manual labor

---

**Note**

Sadly the question has been closed. I was going to add a bounty, but apparently that is not going to happen. Anyway, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions you're thinking of?  Specifically, what size is the colony ship (how many people can be sent; ignoring issues of how many are needed for genetic health)?  What is the technological level (how much automation/robots are there to do manual labour)?  What is the culture of the colony ship (will bias preferences for certain types of profession)?

Comment: What's the motivation for forming the settlement? Scientific research? Economic exploitation of natural resources? People just looking for an alternative lifestyle? Also, how life-friendly is the frontier world? More like a second Earth or more like Mars? And do you need the colony to be self-sustainable or are regular supply shipments possible?

Comment: A race with space travel capabilities, have the technology to store huge amounts of data in small devices. So you will not need advanced specialists per say, rather people with training in a couple of fields, that can understand their stored knowledge and be able to put it to good use (at least for the first generation of settlers). This may allow you to have a greater variety of professionals, at first trip.

Comment: @andrew That was what I was thinking: people with multiple talents or a general craftiness and intelligence. You won't need workers, because drudge work is done by robots.

Comment: @Philipp I wouldn't know. Why did England settle their prisoners in Australia? Why did Europeans settle in or invade the Americas? Probably there were a multitude of reasons at work. Governments wanted space for their growing population, more ressources, power, people wanted a place to live free or just a chance at life at all, others looked for adventure or opportunity, and so on.

Comment: @inappropriateCode Well, since we are *settling*, the terraforming has been done or was unnecessary. So there is water, oxygen, soil, plant life, lower animal life forms. At the same time there is no civilization on that planet, we are not planning a genocide. As for the size of the ship, that will depend on what you need to make the colony work. And if they can settle a planet, most hard work will be done by machines (mining, road building), I guess, but again, it's up to you to make your answer plausible.

Comment: @what The goals of the settlement are important for answering the question because they decide what kind of specialists you need. They also affected the historical examples you provided.

Comment: @Philipp My personal view is that human population growth is the main factor in human expansion, in fact it drove not only our ancestors from Africa all over the world, but it drives all living things to fill every available ecological niche to overflowing. To find space for humans to live in will be the main driving factor in space colonization. Otherwise we would send scientists and adventurers, not settlers.

Comment: You could cut back on education and medicine quite a bit. Humanity has done well even with the bare minimums of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love this question. I really think the answer depends on: what planet are we settling? That changes SO much. Do you colonize a jungle world with it's own life? A barren desert planet? With breathable atmosphere? Or not?

Let's first see what we need.

### We need

- Shelter. Some kind of housing, almost every planet will have storms, weather, sun and maybe rain. So we need shelter. Also shelter allows us to protect from wildlife, and to create facilities for:
- Air. We can have some air reserves on our ship, so we don't need that immediately. maybe the atmosphere is breathable, that would make it easier.
- Water. We can also have reserves here and use handheld water purifiers / extractors for the first months. But we will need water soon. Maybe it exists on our planet in drinkable quality.
- Food. Same as above.

The above things are elementary, no life can exist or be sustained without. The following are less critical.

- Energy: most machines require energy. So we'd either need fusion/ fission generators that we bring along, or fall back to renewable energy or.. a classic... burning stuff.
- Healthcare: We need doctors, medical supplies, a place to perform surgery, psychological support and so on.
- Construction: we need some kind of industry to produce required goos locally.
- Resource gathering: in order to fuel our industy, we need to gather resources somehow.
- Administration: our colony needs a basic administration team to keep track of everything.
- Entertainment: Do not underestimate the need to "vent off some steam" and "kill boredom" from time to time. A place to drink alcohol, listen to and make music, dance, find someone to get laid, play games and these kind of things will be required SOON. Also, these places are usually social gathering places, that fulfil the need for "social contact".
- Prospectors, that research and map the planet you will live on. Also a required thing early on to find the resources you need and a safe place to live.

Of course there is much more, but a post in this forum cannot be more than a rough overview....

### How can we fulfil ALL THESE things with only little staff?

You can't fill out all these requirements with specialists. You need people who are universally trained in more than one area. A doctor for example could also be a psychotherapist, and maybe  also have expertise in biology and microbiology. He could also help out producing drugs and mybe even manufacture chemical compounds. Yes, he will never be an expert heart surgeon, but you simply have to deal with that. People will die because he isn't, but that's life as an early colonist.

So what would i take with me on my way to colonize a planet?

- A big group of doctors with education in pharmacy and biology.
- A group of engineers and a few architects. Each and every one of them must know how to create energy in the new environment.
- A few prospectors, who have degrees in at least biology and geology.
- A few expert construction workers who can take the more difficult task and guide the others while creating shelter and new buildings.
- Soldiers. Loads and loads of soldiers.

Why the soldiers? They are physically fit, can follow orders, are used to working hard and living in simple conditions. They know how to survive, are used to construction working (bridges, sand bags etc..), can hunt food, forage for plants, accompany and protect the prospectors, have basic medical and technical skills, are used to work in hazardous (ABC) environments, and usually come in handy pre-organized units (with their own medic, pioneers, scouts etc...). Having a lot of soldiers also lessens the need for administration early on, as they are already preorganized and administrated.

Also, on more hostile planets, they can protect the other settlers from potentially dangerous wildlife.

You can also easily run your soldiers through a strict and rigid 1-2 years training camp, teaching them the required skills for their trip.

I would also make sure we arrive with a fully equipped microbacterial lab. Local bacteria and virusses seem to be the biggest potential health threat in my opinion.

If there is still room, get someone who knows how to make alcohol, and a few prostitutes as well as some people who can build and maintain instruments... the happyness part IS important.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one that thought of sending soldiers. That said, how difficult is it going to be to psych screen them? Billy Joe from Arkansas has all the qualities we're looking for - He's got mechanical intuition, is a good marksman, and has absolutely unwavering loyalty... But Billy Joe joined the Marines so he could protect America, not so he could stack crates for colonists a trillion miles from a home he'll never see again.

Comment: I'd suggest sappers / military engineers. Worse than regular infantry at combat,  but way better at construction and demolition. With them, you do not need separate construction workers.

Comment: Perhaps the  soldiers could be veterans allowed the right to settle a new world along with generous rights to Homsteads, in a similar manner to that the Roman used to do.

Answer (score 4):

### Anyone willing to pay

All practicalities aside: considering the costs involved in sending living colonists to a distant planet, there will be a degree of willingness to entertain any would-be frontiersman and family who can *pay* to get there. The long-term success or short-term failure of the colony are obviously irrelevant if getting colonists there is cost-prohibitive. If it's a [Gold Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_rush)- or [Homestead Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestead_Acts)-like free-for-all there could be outfits strictly out to make a profit getting colonists to the planet, regardless of their suitability as colonists.

Answer (score 1):

**Who would I send**

1. Agronomists: Growing food on another continent is not too much different here on earth. Still, the early settlers of America nearly starved because the hot/cold and wet/dry cycles are not the same between England and New England. They had to get useful knowledge from the locals. If you are going to another planet, the problems are compounded many-fold. Who knows what strange soil compositions could be doing to your crops? Well...agronomists do.
2. Doctors: Don't leave home without them.
3. Civil Engineers: Some of the first things you will want to do is to build structures. In addition to living structures, your society could need roads for transporting goods, levees for flood control, underground habitats for radiation protection, and more.
4. Metal-workers and mechanics: You don't necessarily need engineers, but you need metalworkers. If you bring heavy agricultural, transportion, or industrial equipment (bulldozers, cranes, tractor-trailers, combines, etc) you need a way to maintain them. If you can't get parts shipped in easily, you have to make and repair parts on site. You don't need to design new stuff. You just need people like your high school shop teacher, except not drunk or creepy.
5. Mining Engineers: Mining was one of the first big activities to happen in the interior US West and in Siberia when the Russians colonized. Establishing mines, ironworks, and cement plants are important to get the building materials needed for the metal-workers and civil engineers.
6. Nuclear operators: Again not necessarily engineers. Depending on the type of energy source, you will need people to run such a plant. With quasi-modern technology, fission or fusion (if available) seems like the logical choice for power generation in a new colony. I'm just not sold on the potential of solar; if you want to run 24-hour mines and ironworks, you need 24 hour power. If you declare the solar + batteries can take care of power needs, then this group is not needed. Due to the complexity of nuclear power, you wouldn't be manufacturing parts or fuel for this one site. Better and easier to import that.
7. Religious leaders: In the real world, a lot of colonization was fueled by the desire for religious freedom. Tight knit groups that don't feel accepted in society are more likely to leave it. The general loss of devotion in the world probably doesn't change that. If you looked at the modern world, who would be most likely to up and leave planet if they had or were given the money to afford it? Probably oppressed Yazidis in Iraq, oppressed Shias in Saudi Arabia, oppressed Copts in Egypt, Christians in Syria, Muslims in Phillipines, Tibetans, Turkish Kurds, etc. The list is long and sad. [The Expanse](https://www.amazon.com/James-S.-A.-Corey/e/B004AQ1W8Y) series makes use of this principle by describing the Mormons as leading the way by building a generation ship for interstellar travel, and presumably, colonization. This also makes an brings up an interesting point: I can't fathom that a colonist group would be primarily American or European. How could you get thousands to want to leave the comfort of Netflix and craft beer?
8. Labor: Lots of work to do, and you need lots of people willing to do it.

**Who I would not send**

1. The old, young, and ill; also whiners, complainers and the lazy
2. There is really no reason not to send people. More people are better; if the world isn't struggling it can support less productive bits of society, if the world is struggling, the less productive will just die.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things to consider ...

#### Training the Next Generation

You mentioned the need for geologists. Surely engineers, too. But in order to teach their successors, you need an university with a solid science department. To train an engineer, you need lecturers in mathematics and theoretical physics, or all you get is a backyard mechanic.

#### Who does the Planning?

You dismissed bankers from your list. Well, in a capitalist society they are an indispensable link between savers and investors. Who will give the farmer a credit for a new combine harvester? Or is there some colony administration to allocate all newly-built agricultural machinery? How can a construction worker save for retirement?

Other "suits" do important work, too. The human resources department is not just there to screw employees, it is *supposed* to put the right people into the right places.

#### The Need for Liberal Arts Majors

Political scientists don't just *observe* and *analyze* the political process, they provide important advice to the political leaders. There are many people who disparage career politicians, but it is difficult to manage a budget process or to write coherent laws. A bunch of amateurs is likely to come up with popular ideas which have severe side effects.

For that matter, humans create culture. If there are no trained observers of the arts scene, that will be preserved only in random bits and pieces, or lost forever.

Comment: Good thinking. You are creating an independent colony. My own first thought was of something like North America, which did not have a lot of universities and banks in the first stages of settlement, because the knowledge was imported, if necessary, and finances where transacted via the home country. And while there were journalists, there wasn't a journalist school. But if you think of a colony to be self-sufficient in the long run, it will certainly need all those. The question is, will they need it during the settlement stage, or will those come with the second fleet?

Comment: Seriously, who is saving and investing? Why do you need human resources bureaucracy? Investing in fair hiring practices is probably just as important as investing in food and shelter. And since when do political scientists provide important advice to political leaders? Have you ever listened to a political analyst or read op-eds in the NYT or WSJ? Those people are gibbering idiots. This is frontier world, no one needs help with politics, they need help feeding themselves. Either get busy working or get busy dying.

Comment: @kingledion, everybody who wants to retire some day needs to save and invest, either individually or through a collective system. And I've experienced plenty of projects that got run into the ground because the technical people thought they'd need no managers.

Comment: A hundred years ago old people in the small country villages were sustained by their children. They did not get, not did they need, a rent. Today, where I live, craftspeople help each other out. I know about every kind of person and never need to pay money for having my car repaired or my roof shingled. In return, I do what I know to do for these people. I don't mean to say we are independent of the money system, but if an exchange economy exists on that level today, it can sure make money redundant.

Comment: @o.m. We live in an advance society of hundreds of millions, interconnected to a world of billions. You need managers to launch and maintain a facebook webpage. You don't need managers to fix a broken tractor or bring in the harvest. Also, retirement is for people who can afford to have other people support them. The knowledge gained by the first generation is so valuable to the second generation, that those initial colonists simply can't stop contributing. Retirement is for a few generations down the road.